# pydantic v2 mark Field required in schema while having defaults

Tags: python-3.x, openapi, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I use pydantic and fastapi to generate openapi specs.
According to the docs, [required fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#required-fields), cannot have default values. However, my discriminator should have a default.

What is the best way to tell pydantic to add `type` to the list of `required` properties (without making it necessary to add a type when instantiating a `Dog(name="scooby")`?

```py
class PetType(str, Enum):
    DOG = "Dog"
    CAT = "Cat"


class Pet(BaseModel):
    name: Annotated[str, Field(..., examples=["Unnamed pet"])]


class Dog(Pet):
    type: Literal[PetType.DOG] = PetType.DOG
```

```json
{
    "title": "Dog",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "examples": [
                "Unnamed pet"
            ],
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
            "const": "Dog",
            "default": "Dog",
            "title": "Type"
        },
    },
    "required": [
        "name",
    ]
}
```

Comment: required means that someone needs to specify the field. if you provide a default value then it is not required.
I would mark this as not required, provide the default value and set some validation.

Comment: I guess thats the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your BaseModel class to make all of its fields required in the generated openapi spec, no matter if they have default values:

```
model_config = ConfigDict(json_schema_serialization_defaults_required=True)
```

See: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.json_schema_serialization_defaults_required

Comment: aye thanks. Will think of your answer when I touch that code again. Hope it works.